# Bootstrap-datepicker uses previous value in popup

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

When a button is clicked, the values of some text fields in a model are loaded and then the modal is shown. Depending of what button is clicked, different dates are loaded into the text fields.

```js
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="editTeamButton" startdate="01-02-2017" enddate="31-12-2017" teamid="1" xrefid="19">Edit</button>

$(document).on("click", "#editTeamButton", function(event){
    $('#xrefid').val($(this).attr("xrefid"));
    $('#editteamid').val($(this).attr("teamid"));
    $('#editteamstartdate').val($(this).attr("startdate"));
    $('#editteamenddate').val($(this).attr("enddate"));
    $('#editTeamModal').modal('show');

    $('.datepickereditteam').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        maxViewMode: 3,
        language: "nl",
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2,3,4,5",
        calendarWeeks: true
    });

});
```

Also, the datepicker plugin is loaded for selecting a date range. This works fine the first time, but the second time `#editTeamButton` is clicked different values are loaded in the fields `editteamstartdate` and `editteamenddate`. Then when clicking a date field, the datepicker uses the date that was previously in there, and not the actual entered date (put there by jQuery `val()`).

How to fix this and make datepicker always use the date that in the text field at the moment of clicking it? I tried destroying datepicker first before loading it, but that does not work. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using

```
$("#editteamstartdate").datepicker("update", $(this).attr("startdate"));
$("#editteamenddate").datepicker("update", $(this).attr("enddate"));
```

instead of

```
$('#editteamstartdate').val($(this).attr("startdate"));
$('#editteamenddate').val($(this).attr("enddate"));
```